# .NET 4.5.1 Preview Support in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package, visual-studio-2013

First let me add some context to error I get, I have installed .NET 4.5.1 Preview and first thing that I noticed in VS 2012 is that .NET 4.5.1 isn't listed in available frameworks. I'm not sure if this is correct behavior because this is just an upgrade to 4.5 so I guess VS 2012 should list it.

Further more when I installed a VS 2013 Preview, upgraded my project to .NET 4.5.1 and opened the solution in VS 2012 new .NET version reappeared so I'm not sure if this is a bug in VS 2012 or not ? Ok so now I have .NET 4.5.1 in VS 2012 and when I try to build a project I get the following error

```
Error   3   The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll". Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  D:\Projects\MyProject\Master\Source\.nuget\nuget.targets    71  9   MyProject.Core.Modules
```

NuGet.targets reported line

```
<SetEnvironmentVariable EnvKey="VisualStudioVersion"
EnvValue="$(VisualStudioVersion)" Condition=" '$(VisualStudioVersion)'
!= '' AND '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' " />
```

It seems to me that for some reason VS 2012 can't resolve the paths or assemblies so I'm not sure if I should fix something in the NuGet.targets or is it a Visual Studio thing, any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: After on small cup of coffee I noticed that I had to upgrade the  _NuGet.targets_.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Build on TFS 2013 failed but okay locally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661943/build-on-tfs-2013-failed-but-okay-locally)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Building .NET Framework 4.5.1 applications is supported in Visual Studio 2012. You need to either install [Visual Studio 2013 Preview](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng#2013-preview) or [Windows SDK for Windows 8.1 Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx) to get the .NET Framework 4.5.1 Preview Targeting pack on the same machine as Visual Studio 2012 to build applications with .NET Framework 4.5.1 preview.

Thanks
Nithya [MSFT]

Comment: Does Microsoft Build Tools 2013 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=40760) do the same job?

Answer (score 17):

i solved changing the ToolsVersion in .csproj file.

From

```
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

To

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

Comment: So you had to change the _ToolsVersion_ back to **4.0** in order to get the **.NET 4.5.1** inside the **VS 2012** ?

Answer (score 7):

To fix this I had to upgrade the *NuGet.targets* and change the following two lines

From

```
<UsingTask TaskName="DownloadNuGet" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
<UsingTask TaskName="SetEnvironmentVariable" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
```

To

```
<UsingTask TaskName="DownloadNuGet" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll">
<UsingTask TaskName="SetEnvironmentVariable" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll">
```

Also it would be nice to get some answers related to .NET 4.5.1 Preview not showing up in VS 2012 up until I installed the VS 2013.

Nice chat with myself.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a blog post that Microsoft wrote on this topic.

[Building apps with the .NET Framework 4.5.1 Preview in Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/08/08/building-apps-with-the-net-framework-4-5-1-preview-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx)