# Create View option is not coming in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Create View option is not coming in my Asp.net mvc project. Please help me. I want to make my view tightly coupled with model.

[image]

Please help me..

Comment: I think he's suggesting the context-menu option for Create View is not showing up when right-clicking on a controller.

Comment: yes, I don't know why that Create view option is not coming ? I've tried closing and reopening my VS 2012

Comment: @SumitChourasia: are you 100% sure that you're rightclicking *inside* a method that returns `ActionResult`?

Comment: yes, I've been working like this for past 4 months, like i don't know why that option is not coming now?

Comment: @SumitChourasia: Did you, by chance, recently upgrade to a new version of Visual Studio?

Comment: No, I just used nu get package to update-database , since I'm using seeding ef database model

Comment: Until you get a good answer on why this stopped working for you, you should be able to right-click on the controller's folder under the  Views folder (or on the shared folder) and add a view there. You can choose to make it strongly typed to a model at that time (from a drop down list of known models - compile first if you don't see a newly-added model to choose).

Comment: See if this answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17696160/729541  It might be that the nuget package needs `ToolsVersion = 4.0` rather than `12.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue, it was because of working with multiple version of Visual Studio.

Created project solution in VS2012 Premium and after a while opened in VS2013 Professional I was not able to Add View by right clicking.

So I closed and re-opened in VS2012 it worked. Hope it helps someone who faces similar issues.

Answer (score -3):

You can only create Views and Controllers in the appropriate folder. You can't, for example, add a view to the Controller folder, or a controller to the View folder.

Comment: Using the contextmenu, you can rightclick an action method in a controller and generate a view file from there.